# Error while trying to run the flutter app in real device

Tags: firebase, flutter

Trying to use my device to run my flutter app ( I have already done this a lot ) but this time for any reason, I'm getting this error. really appreciate it any  help

```
What went wrong:
```

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.pom'.
> > Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

I just found the  reason .i intergraed with the Firebase but forgot modify  ClassPath

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'
  }
```

}